# How to install the QGIS Raster Lang plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I´m trying to install the **rasterlang** plugin for QGIS. I tried several things [on this website](http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~rowlings/Software/Qgis/Plugins/rasterlang/) but it seems to be quite complicated because I need to install binary files and other files.

The idea would be to make it the way that when I type in my console: 
**from rasterlang.layers import layerAsArray** then It would work nicely. Thanks